# How can I obtain the name of the TLS fingerprint algorithm with tcpdump and tshark?

Tags: ssl, tls1.2, tcpdump, tshark, tls1.3

I have a web service and I want to get the tls fingerprint from the client hello package requested by the client. What should I do

I have tried using nginx-ssl-fingerprint(https://github.com/phuslu/nginx-ssl-fingerprint), which can work, but can only obtain TLSVersion, Ciphers, and cannot obtain TLS fingerprint extensions, EllipticCurves, EllipticCurvePointFormats.

[image]

According to the above image I have tried using tcpdump to listen to my server network card, then exporting the PCAP package and outputting it with tshark

But it can only print specific algorithm numbers. I actually want to obtain the name of the tls fingerprint algorithm, but the extensions, EllipticCurves, and EllipticCurvePointFormats cannot be obtained because using the tshark command results in an empty result

**Command Prompt**
[image]

The main tshark cannot be obtained, but it can be obtained using wireshark. I am a bit confused and would like to know which commands are used to obtain these algorithms in the tshark command

like this:

[image]

I'm trying to read the OpenSSL documentation, to be honest, it's a bit obscure and difficult to understand.

Of course, if there were a better way, I would humbly seek advice

Comment: This question makes no sense for me. The TLS fingerprint is not part of the ClientHello but is computed using information from the ClientHello. What you see in Wireshark as JA3 is a computed value, not a value which is included in the ClientHello. See [TLS Fingerprinting with JA3 and JA3S](https://engineering.salesforce.com/tls-fingerprinting-with-ja3-and-ja3s-247362855967/) for more information and how to compute it yourself from the information in the ClientHello.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich 

It's not meaningless, I just want to calculate and identify the client's JA3 fingerprint through TLS fingerprint, and I don't want to take JA3 directly, because now there are many request libraries that can directly fake JA3 fingerprint, I am to verify whether the request is legitimate

Comment: You ask to *"obtain TLS fingerprint extensions"* - but there is no such extension. The process on how to compute the TLS fingerprint JA3 from the information in the ClientHello is documented in the link I've provided in my comment.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich      Sorry, I may not have expressed myself clearly. What I want to obtain is “TLSVersion, Ciphers, Extensions, EllipticCurves, EllipticCurvePoint Formats” for tls. This is my purpose. I know you mentioned ja3, ja3, which I have been using for a long time, but I have found that many crawlers can forge ja3 fingerprints, so I want to obtain TLSVersion, Ciphers, Extensions, EllipticCurves, EllipticCurvePoint Formats to identify whether it is a legitimate request

Comment: But this is what the output of tshark you include already provides. BTW, it is bad style to include images of text - copy and paste (and properly format) the text instead.

Comment: Also, if *"many crawlers can forge ja3 fingerprints,"* this means that they can set *" TLSVersion, Ciphers, Extensions, EllipticCurves, EllipticCurvePoint Formats"* in a specific way, since JA3 is computed from these (again, it is not part of the ClientHello but computed from the ClientHello). So it will not help to obtain the "original" values to detect TLS fingerprint spoofing.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich   Okay, thank you very much for your answer. I'm just curious why Wireshark can output algorithm names, but I can only output values instead of algorithm names using tsshark

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich  Indeed, as you said, advanced crawlers can modify ja3 fingerprints and tls algorithms at the same time. I just want to prevent crawlers as much as possible, because there are still many crawlers that only modify ja3 fingerprints

Comment: *"can modify ja3 fingerprints and tls algorithms at the same time"* - this is like saying that they modify the input and the output of a computation at the same time. But they only modify the input - the output (JA3) is the result of the computation. It is not possible to only modify JA3 and keep the input the same. In short: you gain nothing by trying to observe the input into the fingerprint computation instead of the computed fingerprint.

Comment: *" I'm just curious why Wireshark can output algorithm names"*  - because it has the mapping. These algorithms have predefined numbers and Wireshark just translates the number from the ClientHello into a more human readable name. See [IANA mapping](https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml) for more. But the names do not actually add information, it is the same information as before, only more human readable.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich   Wow, your iana mapping has been a great help to me. Thank you very much, You are right to say that the output cannot be modified. Thank you very much for your answer. I have a new understanding of tls. In my country, few people study this kind of problem. My English is not good, I am sorry for the misunderstanding caused by the previous expression. This is the first time I ask a question on stackflow, thank you for the advice you just gave

Comment: I just found two libraries, scapy and scapy_ssl-tls, after reading the official introduction, I think I can also output tls-related information